# What caused the server outage?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, 500-server-error

Until just a minute ago, I was getting the following error on SO/Meta.SE/other network sites:

> [image: server error]

```
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

[Nick posted on twitter](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1195071424614092801):

> SQL is very, very angry. We're aware and working it.

What actually caused this? And should we expect this to happen more in the future as the reputation recalculation continues to be rolled out?

Comment: Unrelated to recalcs as far as we know - that wrapped up yesterday.

Comment: SQL didn't ask any questions so it didn't gain any rep. Wouldn't you be angry?

Comment: Dammit. Was betting on the recalc overflowing an int somewhere, @AdamLear

Comment: It must have been Jon Skeet reaching 2,147,483,647 points.

Comment: I spilled coffee on the domain controller, sorry.

Comment: My first thought was DoS attack. Users are unhappy. Maybe some of them are programmers.

Comment: @IAmNotTheWayYouSpeak Programmers usually don't destroy the things they've built up over years. They fix them.

Comment: @JonasWilms The hackers mustn't be progammers, I guess.

Comment: @Taryn I see you just added the [status-completed] tag to this question. What was the root cause of the problem, and what changes are being made to prevent it from recurring in the future?

Comment: @RobertColumbia We have theories but no actual cause. I added the tag because this has been answered.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We had an issue with our primary SQL Server that contains the Stack Overflow database and Sites database (which is used by the rest of the network).

We're still investigating the actual cause, but the CPU on the server spiked to 100% and wouldn't allow any queries to the server. We attempted to restart SQL, but had to reboot the server to get things to settle down.

Comment: Yikes, that's super scary. It'll be interesting to hear what the root cause was once y'all identify it. Anything with the power to take the whole network offline for 15+ minutes must be something serious.

Comment: @scohe001 We have ideas on what triggered it but unfortunately we didn't get a full memory dump on the server. We'll be monitoring it and looking for possible fixes.

Comment: I don’t know anything about how this works (I’m a developer in an entirely different domain), but isn’t there a backup server that things would automatically roll over to when the primary goes comatose? A critical bug like this on one server shouldn’t bring the entire network down.

Comment: @CodyGray We use SQL Server Availability Groups for our disaster recovery which can do an automatic failover, but for many reasons we have them set to manual.

Comment: I can't believe you guys aren't serverless yet. Surely that would stop all these server issues ... #ihazsmarts

Comment: If it helps you track it down, I had the error way earlier this morning when I clicked a link.  I *thought* I might have commented that the link is dead at the time, but can't find it in my history.

Comment: > It was me. I did it. I killed the server. Everything was shaking. I lost my balance. I was just trying to hold on to something. I didn't mean to do it.  My arm hit the computer panel. That's what destroyed the ship. DATA: It is not possible. TIMOTHY: Oh...

Comment: @RobertCartaino how did miss this awesome comment?